# UnInstallation of a Plugin from a developers perspective - The correct and clean method

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, uninstallation

I think a good developer should provide the uninstallation in the safest and cleanest possible way.

I downloaded various plugins today to understand the process, but everything was very confusing. I found that many plugins are using both uninstall.php files and 
[`register_uninstall_hook(__FILE__, 'pluginprefix_function_to_run');`](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/the-basics/uninstall-methods/)

Is it correct?

because the link that I have provided above says that these two are two different methods. so what is correct using either registration hook or uninstall.php or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They’re just two different ways of doing the same thing. It’s up to you which one to use, or whether to use both. Neither is ‘correct’. Use whichever makes more sense to you with the structure of your plugin.

Comment: Thanks. You said to use both. How come it is possible - won't they conflict? Please enlighten if possible with an example.

Comment: They'll just both run. There'll only be a conflict if you try to do the same thing in both. I don't know why you'd do that, but I'm not writing your plugin.

Comment: Hi there, Can you write a sample uninstallation function in uninstall.php, if possible?

Comment: No. There's one in your own link.

Comment: I am trying to upvote but not happening why?

Comment: @RichaSharma You were under the [15 rep minimum to cask upvotes](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up), who knew.